# Dynamically display domain images with php or Codeigniter Helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I am developing an application where there are different users related to different domains.
In the admin panel i am adding a domain.
Now i need to display logo of each domain.
How can i dynamically display logo of any domain?
Is there any way that i input a domain name as a string and it returns domains information along with the image.
I know i can upload logos while adding a domain but i want it to do it with a simple helper function.
How can i achieve it.
Let suppose i need a function like this

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('domain_helper');
```

And to find domain

```
<img src = "<?php echo domain_image('https://www.google.com/'); ?>" >
```

Comment: The safe bet would be storing the domain names in database and referencing them with an image in your directory. Depending upon others mean if they change some configuration, all your codes will be broken.

Comment: No, you might have seen avatars related to email addresses. I need to do the same thing.

Comment: Erm haven't seen. Can you give an example site where it is implemented?

Comment: take a look at Usage https://github.com/sekati/codeigniter-gravatar-helper

Comment: @itachi StackOverflow, it uses Gravatars that are attached to your email :)

Comment: @itachi you can see a flower image near my name. This is an example here at Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curl to pull the favicon from the website and save it as a png.

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

```
<?php
$domain = "google.com";
$image_name = "favicon.ico";

touch("/var/www/domain_images/$domain.png");
$fp = fopen("/var/www/domain_images/$domain.png", "w");

$ch = curl_init("https://".$domain."/".$image_name);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

---

### EDIT

**A word of caution**: if you are taking input from users to get the domain name, make sure you sanitize it before passing it along (as always)!